# Does increasing water pressure change how high a column of water can be lifted in a vacuum?

Tags: water, vacuum

If I take a 1 inch square pipe and submerge one end in water and at the other end I create a vacuum, does the height the column of water is lifted in the pipe vary with the depth of the submerged end? For example if the submerged end is at the bottom of the ocean and the water pressure is 15k psi will that cause the column of water to be lifted higher than if the pipe is submerged say 100 feet? If so, how do you calculate that extra height?

Answer (score 0):

If the density of the fluid inside the pipe is everywhere the same as outside, there will be no change: the pressure is the same outside and inside the pipe at its bottom opening, and with the density matching everywhere, that means the pressure at any given height is the same inside and outside the pipe all the way to the surface.

However, if the density is different, this no longer holds.  If the pipe is insulated, and the water inside is heated so that it becomes less dense than the water just on the other side of the pipe wall, the free surface inside the pipe will be higher than outside, and if you apply a vacuum to the top of the pipe, the amount you can lift the water inside will be correspondingly higher.

If the thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha$ is approximated as constant, the change in height will be $\Delta H = \alpha H \Delta T$. At a temperature $T$ of about $20$ C, $\alpha \approx 0.0002$.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Is there a way to calculate how much higher the water would rise for every degree warmer the water inside the pipe is?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: if the pipe was an upside down funnel and the submerged end was very large and in deep water under high pressure while the vacuum end was very small, would that affect how high the water would rise?

Comment: No.  As long as the temperature inside the funnel depends only on height, the shape doesn't matter.